# c# bytes array index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, byte, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm reading for 5 bytes array

```
ReadData = new byte[5];

bytewaiting = Serialcomport.BytesToRead;

while (bytewaiting > 0)

{

   ReadData[i++] = (byte)Serialcomport.ReadByte(); **<--Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array**

   bytewaiting = bytewaiting - 1;

}
```

Comment: Side note: Please read [MCVE] guidance carefully to improve your future questions. `i++` makes no sense in that code as it never declared nor assigned any sensible value.

Answer (score 0):

The receive buffer includes the **serial driver's receive buffer** as well as internal buffering in the `SerialPort` object itself.

Because the `BytesToRead` property represents both the `SerialPort` buffer and the Windows-created buffer, it can **return a greater value than the ReadBufferSize property.**

Instead of watching for the `BytesToRead` you should subscribe to the `DataReceived` event. Then you will automatically be called when new data arrives.

If you don't know how to do this on the above link to the corresponding MSDN page you'll find a example on how to subscribe to the event and what you should do within it.